# Mongoose: Insertar/Actualizar un subdocumento según criterios

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

He visto bastantes ejemplos aquí en stackoverflow, pero ninguno me ha servido ¿Será que mi estructura está mal?

Necesito insertar nuevos registros en un documento anidado usando Mongoose (Quisiera añadir dentro del arreglo `"historial"`). Si el documento ya existe debo solo actualizarlo, si no existe, hay que añadir un nuevo documento. Tengo el siguiente esquema:

```
let equipo_json = {
    codigo: String,
    controles: [{
        _id: con.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        nombre: String,
        historial: [{
            _id: con.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            nuevo: Boolean,
        }]
    }]
};

let equipo_schema = new con.Schema(equipo_json);
let Equipo = con.mongoose.model('Equipo', equipo_schema);
```

Este código debería realizar la actualización:

```
Equipo.update({
  '_id': objeto_equipo.id_equipo,
  'controles._id': objeto_equipo.id_tipo_control
},{
  $set: {
    'controles.$.historial.$': {
      nuevo: true
    }
  }
},
{
  upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true
},
function (err, doc ) {
  console.log( doc );
})
```

Antes de usar `update()` usé `find()` para comprobar que encuentre según el criterio y sí devuelve el documento completo, sin embargo, cuando deseo usar `update()` simplemente no añade al arreglo `"controles"` el campo `"nuevo"` como `"true"`. Probé tanto con `$set` como con `$push`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución a mi problema y la comparto por si a alguien le pasa lo mismo. Solo hay que modificar esta parte del código:

```
'controles.$.historial': {
  nuevo: true
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por compartir esta información. Ya logré hacer la actualización que necesitaba.